# Is there a better way to call a derived class's overridden method from its abstract base class?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I have an abstract base class from which many classes are derived. I want derived classes to be able to override a virtual method defined in the base class, but there is complex logic in the base class that determines whether the overridden method is "enabled" at any particular moment.

Consider this code -- one possible solution -- for example:

```
public abstract class AbstractBaseClass
{
  public bool IsMethodEnabled { get; set; }

  public virtual void DerivedMethod() { }

  public void Method()
  {
    if (IsMethodEnabled)
      DerivedMethod();
  }
}

public class DerivedClass : AbstractBaseClass
{
  public override void DerivedMethod()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("DerivedMethod() was called.");
  }
}
```

In the example above, `IsMethodEnabled` is shorthand for more complex logic that determines whether `DerivedMethod` should be called -- it's code that I want encapsulated in the base class so that I don't have to reproduce it in each derived class.

The design works as intended. If I run this sample code:

```
AbstractBaseClass a1 = new DerivedClass() { IsMethodEnabled = false };
AbstractBaseClass a2 = new DerivedClass() { IsMethodEnabled = true };

a1.Method();
a2.Method();
```

...I see exactly one call to `DerivedMethod`, as expected.

But something rubs me wrong about this implementation. I feel like there must be a more elegant way to handle this. Is there a better way to selectively call a derived class's method implementation from its abstract base class? Is there a design pattern that would better serve me here?

In other words, does the code above "smell"?

Comment: What is inelegant about this?

Comment: Probably make DerivedMethod protected to avoid other classes directly invoking it, but still allowing the subclasses to override it. I would probably also make IsMethodEnabled virtual so some subclasses can alter/augment the check, unless you are dead certain you don't want that. Last, consider protected for IsMethodEnabled  as well (or private if not virtual) unelss it has uses outside the class.  Otherwise looks okay to me.

Comment: @Oli: Nothing necessarily. I guess that's what I'm asking. It feels inelegant to me -- like there should be some better way to handle this with pure polymorphism principles -- but I just don't know.

Comment: @Michael: This is pure polymorphism at work.  You're using dynamic dispatch!

Comment: This seems fine to me. The only comment that I have is that if you dropped the `IsMethodEnabled` property then the code would still behave the same way as the current implementation of `DerivedMethod` does nothing. Are you expecting to override the method in some of your classes yet still have `IsMethodEnabled` set to `false`? If so, why? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Template Method basically is just polymorphism.  I'm not sure how it got to be called a pattern.

Comment: @Enigmativity: IsMethodEnabled is a gross simplification of what's going on. It's just a simple property used here for purposes of illustration. Imagine "if (IsMethodEnabled)" being replaced with something much more complex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a perfectly reasonable implementation.

The main changes I would suggest are:

- Make the virtual method that implements the functionality `protected` instead of public
- Use more appropriate naming for this.  Perhaps something more like `public void Method()` and `protected virtual void OnMethod()`

Comment: Cool. In my real code, I actually use that Method/OnMethod idiom. Good to hear it seconded.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Reed that this is a reasonable implementation.

However, I'd consider the following: who are you trying to protect here? I am all for designing base classes well so that they can be extended easily and safely, but I'm also of the opinion that *the developer writing the derived class knows more than the developer who wrote the base class*. They might know better than you do whether a given method is "enabled" or not.

Comment: That's a valid concern (given how vague I was). IsMethodEnabled probably wasn't the best name for this example. Fortunately, in my case, it's not about protecting derived classes from themselves -- it's about encapsulating a whole lot of complexity in the base class instead of reproducing it in each derived class. Derived classes *want* their method to be disabled sometimes, they just don't want to have to figure out whether or not it should be. I'm still being vague, I know, but it's tough to explain further without writing a whole blog about it :) Anyway, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @Michael, could you elaborate on the "derived classes want their method to be disabled sometimes"? We control access to a method by its visibility level (public, protected, private). When I call a public method, I generally expect it to succeed or fail, but not "not execute". Seems like there might be a problem in the design pattern you're using.

Comment: @Roman: Sure. My base class is a Component for a game. Implementations derive from that class, e.g., PlayerComponent, EnemyComponent, ItemComponent, etc. Components are updated in the main game loop if they optionally overrode the virtual Component method Update(), but they may decide that certain game events deactivate them. Each derived class decides which events deactivate it, but the event management code (and subsequent disabling of Update) is in the abstract Component class so it that doesn't have to be duplicated in derived classes. I probably should've just asked a specific question :)

Comment: @Michael: That makes a fair amount of sense. An even more oop-tacular way to do it would be to abstract the game policy about what deactivates what into a separate class of its own -- a GamePolicy class. That way, a Component is responsible for knowing *how* to disable itself, but not responsible for *knowing when to do so*.  Sometimes keeping policies away from mechanisms is the right thing to do, and sometimes its just unneccessary complexity.

Answer (score 1):

It does not 'smell' more than other [Template Methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern), which are not liked by some people. I tend to agree with some points made [here](http://tech.puredanger.com/2007/07/03/pattern-hate-template/). Especially these two:

> - Difficult to comprehend program flow – In my experience it takes
>     very few levels of template methods and inheritance to make debugging
>     or understand the sequence of method calls difficult (as few as 2 or
>     3). When template methods are really pushed (lots of abstract methods
>     at multiple levels), it can become painful to debug this kind of a
>     system.
> - Difficult to maintain – Having maintained a couple chunks of code
>     that made extensive use of the template method, it can be challenging.
>     This kind of system can rapidly become fragile. Changes at any one
>     level can disturb operation above or below that level in the template
>     methods. There is often a feeling of unpredictability when adding new
>     functionality as it difficult to predict how behavior will change in
>     all cases. You often also tend to build finer and finer tweaks by
>     splitting the algorithmic parts of the template class and inserting
>     more layers, thus exacerbating the problem.

Generally speaking I think you have to be very careful with Template Method and keep things simple and focused.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're trying to decouple the *decision* about calling a method from the method itself. If the *sole* reason to have the base class is to encapsulate that decision, and make its code reusable, I think you could use a more loosely-coupled design, which would ease testing each behavior separately:

```
public interface IDoSomething {
  void Method();
}

public class ConditionallyDoSomething : IDoSomething {
  private IDoSomething _wrapped;

  public ConditionallyDoSomething(IDoSomething wrapped) {
    _wrapped = wrapped;
  }

  public bool IsMethodEnabled { get; set; } // could be quite complex...

  public void Method() {
    if (IsMethodEnabled) {
      _wrapped.Method();
    }
  }
}

public class DoSomething : IDoSomething {
  public void Method() {
    // do something...
  }
}
```

This way, you can mock `IDoSomething`s and test each piece (decision making and functionality) separately. But this is only warranted if you really have some complex logic in both behaviors that would benefit from such separation. I'm just trying to give an alternative to the other excellent answers here. Ultimately, it depends on your specific scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You could just mark all methods that are required to be overriden as abstract and those methods that could be optionally overriden as virtual. See [C# Abstract Classes](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Understanding_C_Sharp_Abstract_Classes)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how expensive IsMethodEnabled (really) is, assuming it isn't the compiler generated one as shown, and whether IsMethodEnabled is going to change frequently, and whether there are hundreds of methods with that little "is enabled" bit of logic there, and whether Method() is a really performance critical path.